# Can I use only Ubuntu as my custom Pc OS?

Tags: support, free

First of all, I've been really excited about giving some support to free software, at least by using them. Not only as alternatives, but as substitutes. I am studying animation and digital arts and have got all the needed software for free, leaving Adobe and Autodesk 90% away of my life. Now I'm interested in using a free OS such as Ubuntu.

From what I have read, everything I use so far is available for Ubuntu, except for my games. I currently run Ubuntu in a virtual machine and it looks pretty good for me. But a friend told me that installing only Ubuntu as my main OS may give me trouble or even get to damage physical parts of my computer, mostly because of the drivers.

I would like to know if that is true. Despite any answer, I would like to know if there's any warranty I could get if I become a 100% Ubuntu user.

I've been really enthusiastic after hearing about this free and professional OS and would appreciate your sincere answer a lot.

Comment: "I would like to know if that is true. "It's not, if you had a specific issue please consider editing your question or opening a new one to reflect this.

Comment: Your friend either knows absolutely nothing about computers, is confusing his computer knowledge, or doesn't want you to install Linux (probably an undercover Microsoft agent).

Comment: Can you tell us what hardware you are using ? I can tell you by experience that most hardware work just fine with Linux. The main point to be aware of is graphic card : which one are you using ?

Comment: I have a Nvidia GForce GTX780, I think that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Software can not destroy hardware, unless you connect a USB-powered explosive kit to your computer...

The only way how the system *could* damage your machine in a not reversible way is by overheating your devices, but before this happens, the BIOS will do an emergency shutdown to save your chips. And although Ubuntu has some minor problems with a handful of drivers, especially for graphic cards, which may lead to inefficient power and fan management, this is only very very rarely a problem and just leads to that described shutdown.

But I don't understand why your friend warns you from installing Ubuntu as only OS for that reason. It's completely irrelevant how the rest of the disk looks like, whether I dual-boot with other systems or not, the running system controls the computer. There is no difference in whether you still have Windows as second OS installed or not, as long as you're running Ubuntu, you're just plainly running Ubuntu.

There is no risk in damaging anything except your current data (which you always have when repartitioning your disk and installing a new system - not only with Ubuntu), but when you make a backup before running the installer, you're on the safe side.

To conclude: Ubuntu does not harm anybody or anything. If you like it, install it. It does not matter if you replace Windows with it or install both along each other on the same computer, do what you feel more comfortable with. Make sure you have got a current backup of your data and nothing bad will ruin your day! :)

Comment: **ByteCommander:**+1 for the explosive USB stick... **@HoangJo:** As you're a reputation 11 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Thanks, this makes me feel more confident. Still, I'll try to be careful with everything. Trying to make a full free-software machine, hoping that the world will let me do it. Games are gonna be a problem, though.

Comment: Carefulness is always a good thing. And about games - there are many good games written for Linux as well in the repositories, or you can use `wine` or `steam` to run other games.